# How can I open the share sheet from my website?

Tags: ios-sharesheet

Is it possible to use the share sheet on my website for IOS and Mac devices?

And if it´s possible then how?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is possible using Web Share API.

Check here for more detail:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator/share

Example:
https://mdn.github.io/dom-examples/web-share/

Source code of example:
https://github.com/mdn/dom-examples/blob/master/web-share/index.html